# What is the most efficient algorithm for getting the antecedent set from the reachability matrix of a matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, sparse-matrix

I have a reachability matrix in the form of a hashmap. The keys are the row numbers and the values are the list of columns which are non-zero for the reachability matrix. I want to generate the antecedent set from this matrix. It is developed by reading the non-zero entries for each column. The matrix has 5000 rows. If I want to use for loop to check whether each key is there in the value set of each key then the number of iterations i 5000*5000. I want to avoid this. Is there any efficient algortihm which can avoid this many iterations.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach is to iterate over the values that *are* in the matrix, instead of the values that *could* be in the matrix. Since the matrix is organized by rows instead of by columns, that means navigating it the same way:

```
final Map<Integer, List<Integer>> reverseReachabilityMatrix = new HashMap<>();
for (final Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> reachabilityMatrixRow :
        reachabilityMatrix.entrySet()) {
    final Integer rowNumber = reachabilityMatrixRow.getKey();
    final List<Integer> columnNumbers = reachabilityMatrixRow.getValue();
    for (final Integer columnNumber : columnNumbers) {
         if (!reverseReachabilityMatrix.containsKey(columnNumber)) {
             reverseReachabilityMatrix.put(columnNumber, new ArrayList<>());
         }
         reverseReachabilityMatrix.get(columnNumber).add(rowNumber);
    }
}
```

(where `reverseReachabilityMatrix` is simply a columnwise representation of the same matrix).

(Note: the resulting lists in `reverseReachabilityMatrix` will not be in any meaningful order. If you need them to be, then you'll need to adjust the above in some way. For example, you can use `for (int rowNumber = 1; rowNumber <= numRows; ++rowNumber)` instead of iterating over the HashMap in its internal order.)

---

Incidentally, although I preserved the `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>` structure above for consistency with what you've already got, I must say that `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>` does not seem like the right data-structure here, for two reasons:

- If your row numbers are 1 through *n*, and if the majority of rows have at least one nonzero entry, then it's much more efficient (both time-wise and space-wise) to use an array or ArrayList structure. That won't change the asymptotic complexity, but it should make a noticeable difference in the actual runtime.
- It seems like `contains` is going to be a common operation here; you will very frequently want to check if the reachability-list for a given row-number includes a given column-number. So a `Set`, such as a `TreeSet`, seems more appropriate. (With an `ArrayList`, the `contains` method has to iterate through the whole list.)

Comment: thanks a lot. This actually solves my problem in finding the transpose of the matrix .

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing just the non-zero elements in a smaller matrix and keep the count of the zero elements for each column?